# Error: “has been blocked by CORS policy" en Angular

Tags: angular

Recibo este error en Angular cuando hago una llamada al servidor PHP.
Este es el error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://p/angular/php/login.php' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

En el php solo tengo un `echo "1";` y la instrucción `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');`

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import {Router} from '@angular/router';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


    @Component({
      selector: 'app-api-login',
      templateUrl: './api-login.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['../app.component.css']
    })


    export class ApiLoginComponent implements OnInit {
      usuario: String="";
      clave: String="";
      url: string; 
      display: String;


      constructor(public router: Router, private http: HttpClient){ 
        this.url="https://pr.es/angular/php/login.php"
        this.display="block";

      }

    ngOnInit() {}

    closeModal(){
      this.display='none';
    }


    login(usuario, clave){ //Metodo

      this.usuario=usuario.value;
      this.clave=clave.value;

      const req = this.http.post(this.url,{
        usuario: 'PrecaNuevo',
        clave: 'PrecaNuevo'
        })
        .subscribe(
          res => {
            console.log(res);
          },
          err => {
            console.log("Error occured");
          }
        );

    }


    }
```

He intentado configurar un proxy segun he leido en algún manual 
En mi package.json tengo entre otras cosas

```
"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json",
```

Y mi archivo **proxy.config.json** que esta en el mismo directorio.

```
  {
        "/angular/php/*":{
          "target": "https://pr.es/",
          "secure": false,
          "logLevel":"debug"
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

prueba con algo como esto, a ver si te lo soluciona:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
header("Allow: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
if($method == "OPTIONS") {
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

El protocolo CORS hace que el navegador complete primero una petición `OPTIONS`, antes de hacer un `GET` o un `POST`, tienes que devolver el encabezado ahí.

Además deberías añadir
otro encabezado, `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` con un valor similar a `GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD`.

Otra opción es configurar un proxy inverso, puedes verlo [en esta otra respuesta a un problema similar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/168993/como-soluciono-el-problema-de-cors-en-javaee-y-angular/175046#175046)

Y, además, puedes encontrar más información sobre CORS [en esta completísima respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/218426/falta-la-cabecera-cors-access-control-allow-origin)

Answer (score 0):

también puede servir una extensión de chrome
[extensión Cors](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf) 
Asegurarse de activarlo.
Aclaro que no es la mejor manera de solucionarlo, pero puede ayudar

Answer (score 0):

También puedes agregar al comienzo de tu archivo el siguiente bloque de código:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE'); 
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow- 
Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With');

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
 http_response_code(200);
 exit();
}
```