# ¿Access to XMLHttpRequest has been blocked by CORS policy?

Tags: reactjs, aws

detalles del error que me soltó por consola

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://89syTyZ8lk5.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev/send' from origin 'https://dev.d2u2t6xd.amplifyapp.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

xhr.js:177 POST https://89syTyZ8lk5.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev/send net::ERR_FAILED
```

en contexto la situación es que subi una pagina hecha con React en amplify y creé una función que está en el servicio lambda y api

en cuanto a lo que quiero hacer es enviar un formulario usando SES en cuanto a como estoy enviando el formulario. Lo estoy haciendo con axios. antes de comentar aqui había leído que tenias que activar los cors desde la consola del **Amazon api Gateway**. hice eso y el error me sigue dando

cambie un poco el axios y lo puse asi

```
axios({
                method: 'post',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
                },
                url:'https://zaxxa5cxx2.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev/contact',
                data: JSON.stringify(Datos),
              })
              .then(res => {
                if (res.data.status === "success"){
                    console.log("Message Sent")
                }})
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err.message ? err.message : 'Unknown error');
                });
```

mi función en lambda esta asi

```
const Response = require('./Response.js')
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const ses = new AWS.SES();

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
// Config//
app.use(cors()); 
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

const RECEIVERS = process.env.RECIVER;
const SENDER = process.env.SENDER ; 

exports.handler = async (event,req) => {
    console.log('Received event:', event);
    
    const params = {
            Destination: {
                ToAddresses: RECEIVERS
            },
            Message: {
                Body: {
                    Html: {
                        Data: `<h1>Details</h1>
                        <p>CLIENTE:${req.body.NOMBRE}</p>
                        <p>CONTACTO:${req.body.EMAIL}</p>
                        <p>Asunto:${req.body.SUBJECT}</p>
                        <p>MENSAJE DEL CLIENTE:${req.body.MESSAGE}</p>
                     `
                    }
                },
                Subject: {
                Data: 'Portfolio Contact',
                Charset: 'UTF-8'
            }
        },
        Source: SENDER
            
    };

    try {
        await ses.sendEmail(params).promise();
        return Response._200({});
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error sending email ', error);
        return Response._400({ message: 'The email failed to send' });
    }
};
```

Comment: Qué es CORS? Leer [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/220984/6798).

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Error: “has been blocked by CORS policy" en Angular](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/253629/error-has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy-en-angular)

Comment: basicamente es establecer los cors. pero eso yo ya lo hice en apartado de axios le agrege el headers{}