# Error Angular + SpringBoot: has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

Soy nuevo utilizando Angular con SpringBoot, en mi proyecto agrego la etiqueta @CrossOrigin para evitar el bloqueo de CORS en la ejecucion de proyecto, pero me sigue saliendo el mismo error.

Error: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/springboot-crud-rest/api/v1/employees' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 ...
 import com.exception.ResourceNotFoundException;
 import com.model.Employee;
 import com.repository.EmployeeRepository;

 @CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:4200")
 @RestController 
 @RequestMapping("/api/v1")
 public class EmployeeController {  

 @Autowired
 private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

 @GetMapping("/employees")
 public List<Employee> getAllEmployees(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {       
     return employeeRepository.findAll();
 }

 @GetMapping("/employees/{id}")
 public ResponseEntity<Employee> getEmployeeById(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long employeeId)
     throws ResourceNotFoundException {
     Employee employee = employeeRepository.findById(employeeId)
      .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Employee not found for this id :: " + employeeId));
     return ResponseEntity.ok().body(employee);
 }

 @PostMapping("/employees")
 public Employee createEmployee(@Valid @RequestBody Employee employee) {
     return employeeRepository.save(employee);
 }
 ...
```

Enn el archivo employee.service.ts de mi proyecto Angular agrego la ruta de mi proyecto SpringBoot.

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
 import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

 @Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
 })
 export class EmployeeService {

 private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/springboot-crud-rest/api/v1/employees';

 constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

 getEmployee(id: number): Observable<any> {
     return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/${id}`);
 }

 createEmployee(employee: Object): Observable<Object> {
     return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}`, employee);
 }

 updateEmployee(id: number, value: any): Observable<Object> {
     return this.http.put(`${this.baseUrl}/${id}`, value);
 }

 deleteEmployee(id: number): Observable<any> {
     return this.http.delete(`${this.baseUrl}/${id}`, { responseType: 'text' });
 }

 getEmployeesList(): Observable<any> {
     return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}`);
 }
}
```

Comment: Muy relacionado: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/175046/22851

Answer (score 2):

Hace poco también tuve ese problema y lo solucioné de la siguiente manera. En la clase principal agregué el siguiente Bean:

```
        @Bean
        public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
            return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
                @Override
                public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                    registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*").allowedMethods("GET", "POST","PUT", "DELETE");
                }
            };
        }
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: En el post mencionado @JackNavaRow, se menciona lo siguiente: _"el asterisco suele ser útil si tienes una API expuesta (pública), en caso contrario, es recomendable no usarlo."_ Vale la pena leer el post antes de implementar esta solucion.