# Eliminar un usuario con Angular y Springboot

Tags: angular, spring-boot

aquí dejo mi problema que llevo horas en el,  a ver si me pueden echar una mano, por favor...

Lo que pasa es lo siguiente, mi api rest funciona correctamente el borrar el usuario y me lo borra de la base de datos (SQL Server), lo probé mediante Swagger UI, pero al momento de conectarlo al angular y ejecutar la función, no me funciona o no me da el resultado esperado, acá les dejo el código, para que puedan ver mejor. Aun no tengo una solución :C

Esto es mi component.ts

```
  borrar(rut: number){
if (confirm("¿Estas seguro que te quieres dar de baja?")) {
  alert("Esperamos verte por acá pronto");
  this.usuariosService.darBajaUsuarios(rut)
  .subscribe(_=>this.volver());
} else { 
  alert("Estamos agradecidos que te hayas quedado con nosotros :D");
}
}
```

Acá esta mi servicio usuario, que es el que llama el api rest.

```
  darBajaUsuarios(rut: number) {
const suffix = '/DarDeBajaUsuario/'
return this.http.post(this.URL+suffix+rut, this.httpOptions);
}
```

Y acá el botón en el html que activa la función.

```
    <button mat-raised-button color="warn" style="margin-right: 10px;" (click)="borrar(rut.value)" 
    routerLink="/bienvenido/">Dar de Baja</button>
```

El error que esto me muestra en la consola seria este. Disculpen que agregue la imagen, pero creo que se visualiza mejor así.

[image: ERROR DE CONSOLA]
Sin mas nada que agregar, gracias, si necesitan algo mas de código, del backend, se los muestro, gracias de antemano por el tiempo dedicado.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Como soluciono el problema de CORS en JavaEE y Angular](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/168993/como-soluciono-el-problema-de-cors-en-javaee-y-angular)

Comment: Hola, gracias pero no me funciona :C, no es un problema de conexión por cross origin, ya que tengo otros métodos api rest y si funcionan, por lo que me lleva a pensar que es la conexión del angular con el api rest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Queria comentarles, que acabo de terminar el proyecto de mi presentacion, mi error era que lo tenia asi:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/DarDeBajaUsuario/{rut}")
public void darBajaUsuarios(@RequestBody Usuarios usuarios) throws SQLException {
    UsuarioDAO.setRutRespuestaVacio(usuarios.getRut());
    UsuarioDAO.setRutReclamosVacio(usuarios.getRut());
    UsuarioDAO.darBajaUsuario(usuarios.getRut());
}
```

Y no estaban llegando bien los parametros del JSON y lo cambie a:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/DarDeBajaUsuario/{rut}")
public void darBajaUsuarios(@PathVariable("rut") int rut) throws SQLException {
    UsuarioDAO.setRutRespuestaVacio(rut);
    UsuarioDAO.setRutReclamosVacio(rut);
    UsuarioDAO.darBajaUsuario(rut);
}
```

Y funciono, muchas gracias. :D