# Error Cors Origin

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, cors, spring-security

estoy haciendo una app con angular y spring boot, donde muestro una serie de productos(videojuegos) y al dar en ver detalles del producto me lanza este error la consola:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'http://localhost:8080/api/test//undefined' from origin
> 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

Tengo una clase que se encarga de dar acceso a una url en spring esta es mi clase:

```
  @Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        // securedEnabled = true,
        // jsr250Enabled = true,
        prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;

    @Bean
    public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new AuthTokenFilter();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/test/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

Y esta es mi clase testController

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/test")
public class TestController {
    @GetMapping("/all")
    public String allAccess() {
        return "Public Content.";
    }

    @GetMapping("/user")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER') or hasRole('MODERATOR') or hasRole('ADMIN')")
    public String userAccess() {
        return "User Content.";
    }

    @GetMapping("/mod")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('MODERATOR')")
    public String moderatorAccess() {
        return "Moderator Board.";
    }

    @GetMapping("/admin")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    public String adminAccess() {
        return "Admin Board.";
    }

    @Autowired
    ProductoService productoService;

    @GetMapping("/lista")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Producto>> getLista() {
        List<Producto> lista = productoService.getAllProducts();
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Producto>>(lista, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
    @GetMapping("/detalle/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getOne(@PathVariable Long id) {
        if (!productoService.existePorId(id))
            return new ResponseEntity<String>("Error producto no encontrado", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        Producto producto = productoService.obtenerPorId(id).get();
        return new ResponseEntity<Producto>(producto, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PostMapping("nuevo")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('MODERATOR') or hasRole('ADMIN')")
    public ResponseEntity<?> create(@RequestBody Producto producto) {
        if (producto.getPrecio() < 0)
            return new ResponseEntity<String>("Error: debes asignar un precio superior o igual a 0",
                    HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        productoService.addProducto(producto);
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("producto guardado", HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @PutMapping("/actualizar/{id}")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('MODERATOR') or hasRole('ADMIN')")
    public ResponseEntity<?> update(@RequestBody Producto producto, @PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        if (!productoService.existePorId(id))
            return new ResponseEntity<String>("no existe ese producto", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(producto.getNombreProducto()))
            return new ResponseEntity<String>("el nombre es obligatorio", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        if (producto.getPrecio() < 0)
            return new ResponseEntity<String>("el precio debe ser superior o igual a 0", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        Producto prodUpdate = productoService.obtenerPorId(id).get();
        prodUpdate.setNombreProducto(producto.getNombreProducto());
        prodUpdate.setIdioma(producto.getIdioma());
        prodUpdate.setDescuento(producto.getDescuento());
        prodUpdate.setUnidades(producto.getUnidades());
        prodUpdate.setPrecio(producto.getPrecio());
        prodUpdate.setDescripcion(producto.getDescripcion());
        prodUpdate.setImagen(producto.getImagen());
        prodUpdate.setFechaLanzamiento(producto.getFechaLanzamiento());
        prodUpdate.setPlataforma(producto.getPlataforma());
        productoService.addProducto(prodUpdate);
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("producto actualizado", HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/borrar/{id}")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('MODERATOR') or hasRole('ADMIN')")
    public ResponseEntity<?> delete(@PathVariable Long id) {
        if (!productoService.existePorId(id))
            return new ResponseEntity<String>("no existe ese producto", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        productoService.deleteProducto(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("producto eliminado", HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

Le agregue a la clase WebSecurityConfig en el metodo  configure justo debajo de la linea .antMatchers("/api/test/**).permitAll agregue .antMatchers("/api/test/detalle/**).permitAll pero aun asi me siguió saltando el error en la consola, alguna ayuda por favor gracias de antemano

Comment: Un consejo *off-topic*: elimina el verbo de las URL de tu API. Si el método HTTP es DELETE, no necesitas `/borrar/` en la URL

Comment: Por otro lado, se me ocurre que podrías usar esta solución: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/175046/22851

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/218426/falta-la-cabecera-cors-access-control-allow-origin)

Comment: Menciona que servidor de aplicaciones usas. El cors se resuelve con configuración en el servidor de aplicaciones, pero depende de cual uses.

Comment: He probado con lo de falta la cabecera que puse @Alfabravo pero no funciona, lo raro es que en el error de la consola del navegador pone undefined en la url 'http://localhost:8080/api/test//undefined'  y escribiendo http://localhost:8080/api/test/detalle/2 por ejemplo me devuelve datos, pero claro al usar el 4200 pues el cors empieza a dar por saco a ver si averiguo esto que siempre me ha dado problemas

Comment: @abrahamhs como servidor de aplicaciones? solo uso spring boot,mysql y angular no se a que te refieres con eso

Comment: Glassfish, tomcat, jboss, OAS, Websphere, etc. etc.

Comment: Pues no uso nada de eso, pero bueno lo solucione ya, resulta que tenia un metodo repetido de haber copiado de otro proyecto que tenía y luego creé un proxy en angular para ahorrarme el cors y ya me funciona todo correctamente gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Primero que todo, échale un vistazo tu endpoint 'http://localhost:8080/api/test//undefined'. Te sobra un slash y al parecer no se está formando la última parte del endpoint y te da undefined.

**¿Qué te está ocurriendo a nivel de CORS?**

El problema de CORS se da por contenido cruzado entre sitios de distinto origen.

Normalmente viene dado por porque haces peticiones desde tusitio.com a  otrositio.co, por ejemeplo. Estos no es el mismo origen, incluso si haces una petición entre http://localhost:8080 a http://localhost:4200 tampoco se consideraría el mismo origen ya que se comunican por puertos distintos.

¿Quién produce este error?
Esto es una política de seguridad de todos los navegadores modernos y son quienes bloquean la respuesta del servidor cuando la respuesta no trae consigo la cabecera **Access-Control-Allow-Origin**.

**¿Cómo solucionarlo?**

Debes añadir a cada respuesta de tu servidor el header **Access-Control-Allow-Origin**

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

La wildcard * significa que tu servidor, aceptará peticiones de cualquier sitio, por lo que enviará el header a cualquiera que le haga peticiones.

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200 // Añadir aquí donde está el front de tu APP

securizarás y te asegurarás que solo tusitio.com pueda hacer peticiones a tu servidor y tu servidor responda con el header (Access-Control-Allow-Origin) para que el navegador acepte su respuesta y no la bloquee.

**¿Por qué la petición si funciona con CURL, Postman o SOAP UI?**

Funciona porque como te comenté, es algo único de los navegadores como medida de seguridad.

**Solución no definitiva:**

Para ir probando tus endpoints mientras defines dónde enviar la cabecera, puedes hacer uso de la extensión para Chrome **Allow CORS: Access-Control-Allow-Origin**, esto activará o desactivará CORS a nivel navegador.

Pero ¡ojo! solo funciona si el navegador de la persona tiene instala la extensión y tiene activado CORS.