# Error bloqueado por CORS en Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Al usar esta api para el uso del trm de Colombia

```
usdToCop() {
    


    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
 
     const url = 'https://trm-colombia.vercel.app/?date=2018-12-31';
    
     return this.http.get(  url,  { headers }
      ).pipe(map((response: any) => {
       
       
       let respuesta = response.data; 
        
        console.log(respuesta);
 
        return respuesta
      }));

  }
```

Me arroja el siguiente error en la consola del navegador

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://trm-colombia.vercel.app/?date=2018-12-31' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

como puedo solucionarlo desde el front sin tocar el back?

Comment: Tienes que tocar necesariamente **tu** back, para que funcione como un proxy inverso. Te recomiendo que mires esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/168993/como-soluciono-el-problema-de-cors-en-javaee-y-angular/175046#175046

Comment: El problema es que te falta crear una suscripción del observable

Comment: @JeffersonCuji y como podría hacer eso me das un ejemplo por favor? De echo este lo consumoen otro lado me suscribo desde otro lado pero pues igual la suscripcion de queda bien por que no pasa ninguna informacion a suscribirse ya que me sale ese error

Comment: pensé que no agregaste la parte de la suscripción, aún así es raro que te muestre un error de cors debido a que es una api pública que incluso puedes acceder desde HTTP. Probé tu código y consume normal la api ¿Quizá tienes algún interceptor?

Comment: @JeffersonCuji pues la verdad no sabria por lo que el proyecto maneja back y de el back si no tengo idea que podria ser ahi la solucion